# Excel Vlookup Issue given matching ID from sheet2 to insert into sheet1

Tags: excel, vlookup

Given sheet1 and sheet2, I am trying to update the product names with matching ID's, in my case is the UPC of the products.  I want to update the product names if the ID matches from sheet2 into column C which is empty.  From there I will choose the product name to keep..  I have tried various Vlookups and None have worked.  I would need to drag it to all the cells.

Sheet1:
A                  B                         C
1820000260  BUD PROJECT 12 SNGL BTL
1820000261  BUSCH BOTTLE
1820000262  BUSCH LT 1/22B
1820000263  BUDWEISER 1/16PL
1820000266  BUD LT LI

Sheet2
A                    B
1820000261  Busch 1/22B
1820000231  Busch 1/24C
1820000070  Busch 1/32B
1820000146  Busch 1/40B
1820000205  Busch 1/7L

Thanks to anyone willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)
```

and also visit [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help).